# Save after Sheets.Copy without using ActiveWorkbook

Tags: vba, excel

I don't like using `ActiveWorkbook`. Is it possible to rewrite the following code without using `ActiveWorkbook` while also sticking to `Sheets.Copy`

```
Sub test()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Lists", "Input", "ListsPars")).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "Palim.xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: The alternative is `Workbooks(x)` where `x` is it's name or index.

Comment: @AlexK. a *better* alternative is to hold on to the workbook reference when your code creates or opens it (assuming that's the case) - like in DisplayName's answer below =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub test()
    With Workbooks.Add ' add a new workbook and reference it
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Lists", "Input", "ListsPars")).Copy after:=.Worksheets(1) ' copy wanted sheets from 'ThisWorkbook' after reference workbook first sheet
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' prevent alert coming form subsequent sheet deletion statament
        .Worksheets(1).Delete ' delete referenced workbook first sheet
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'restore alerts back on
        .SaveAs "Palim.xlsx" ' save referenced workbook
        .Close ' close referenced workbook
    End With
End Sub
```